# ECDHE-PSK mbedTLS example?

Tags: encryption, mbed, polarssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to figure out how to use mbedTLS (formerly PolarSSL) to perform ECDHE-PSK encryption between two peers. Unfortunately, there isn't any article/documentation whatsoever on APIs that I need to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ECDHE-PSK is a key exchange method used in TLS. You should first have a look at the mbed TLS [TLS tutorial](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/how-to/mbedtls-tutorial).

Then you need to configure the pre-shared key on both ends. This usually involves using [`mbedtls_ssl_conf_psk()`](https://tls.mbed.org/api/ssl_8h.html#a1e185199e3ff613bdd1c8231a19e24fc) client-side and, though the same function could in theory be used server-side too if you only expect to communicate with a single client, in practice most of the time you'll want to use [`mbedtls_ssl_conf_psk_cb()`](https://tls.mbed.org/api/ssl_8h.html#a1b804626a236e493316c58b048ab5937) to set up a callback function that will select the appropriate pre-shared key for each client.

You also need to adjust the list of allowed ciphersuites. This can be done at runtime using [`mbedtls_ssl_conf_ciphersuites()`](https://tls.mbed.org/api/ssl_8h.html#ac8e4df37cadda8f743ed45501a51fec1). Alternatively, if you know you'll only use ECDHE-PSK, you can [customize your build](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/compiling-and-building/how-do-i-configure-mbedtls) to disable all other key exchanges, which will also minimize your footprint.

Finally, you can find fully working examples of doing TLS with various ciphersuites, including based on ECDHE-PSK in the mbed TLS distribution as [ssl_client2.c](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/programs/ssl/ssl_client2.c) and [ssl_server2.c](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/programs/ssl/ssl_server2.c). You can check how the functions mentioned above are used in the examples, and in particular you'll find an example of server-side [PSK callback](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/programs/ssl/ssl_server2.c#L730).